# C++ operator= overload works selectively

Tags: c++

I appear to have an assignment operator that works circumstatially.
I have a Vector2 class which contains two float's, x and y.
Here is the operator= method:

```
Vector2 Vector2::operator=(const Vector2 &right)
{
    Vector2 result;
    result.x = right.x;
    result.y = right.y;
    return result;
}
```

Within an onMove method for an entity I have:

```
Vector2 newPosition = position + (speed * getSpeedFactor());

if (posValid(newPosition))
{
    position.x = newPosition.x;
    position.y = newPosition.y;
    //position = newPosition;
}
```

Where speedFactor depends on framerate and posValid is a check for whether a point is in a wall or something. position and speed are also Vector2's.
The first assignment:

```
Vector2 newPosition = position + (speed * getSpeedFactor());
```

works, and with the code as is I get the expected/intended behaviour, however

```
position = newPosition;
```

has no effect, whether on it's own or before or after the .x & .y assignments.

Comment: The first one is **NOT** the assignment operator, it's the constructor. Also, you should be returning `Vector2 &`. It's also being called on an object, so you should be modifying the object, not a temporary result.

Comment: operator= should return a reference to itself, normally.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 14):

Your `operator=()` is wrong, it should modify the current object, not the extra you create

```
Vector2& Vector2::operator=(const Vector2 &right) 
{
  x = right.x; 
  y = right.y; 
  return *this; 
}
```

*Note*: the return type is a reference and you are returning the reference to the current object, not a copy of it (or of a new one like in your code).

The reason it worked for

```
Vector2 newPosition = ...;
```

is because this is not *default-construct + assignment* but a *copy-construct* call.

Comment: *"is because the compiler optimized away the default-construct+assignment to a copy-construct call"* -- It's not an optimization.  When `=` is used in an initialization, it is not assignment, it is a call to the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually assigning to `position`.  You are making a temporary `Vector2` object, assigning to it, then implicitly copying it and returning the copy.  You are never modifying the actual object.

You need something like:

```
Vector2& Vector2::operator=(const Vector2 &right)
{
    x = right.x;
    y = right.y;
    return *this;
}
```